# How to disable a product using Id in phtml?

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, user-roles, stock-status

I need to disable a product which is added by specific role. My code below:

```
    $role_id = 1 ; //get user's role id from system configuration
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $adminSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
     $current_adminuser =    $adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleId();
    if($role_id == $current_adminuser): ?>
    <?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);
$product->setStoreId(0); // you can set store id here
$product->setStatus(2); // 2 => Disable , 1 => Enable
$product->save();
```

This returns fatal error because of bootstrap.php file. Else can I disable produc using product id with raw sql?

Comment: No I need this function to work when new product added..so I added phtml in product add page and written in that

Answer (score 0):

Got answer. This worked fine for me

```
 $role_id = 1 ; //get user's role id from system configuration
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $adminSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
     $current_adminuser =    $adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleId();
    if($role_id == $current_adminuser): ?>

    <?php

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $storeId = '1';
   $product_id = 489;
$productFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(489);

$productFactory->setStoreId(1); // you can set store id here
$productFactory->setStatus(2); // 2 => Disable , 1 => Enable
$productFactory->save();
```